# HTTP "Accept" header: how to specify multiple acceptable content-types?

Tags: http, http-headers, mime-types

After reading through [RFC 7231](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-5.3.2) and searching online, I'm not clear on how an HTTP request should indicate that they can accept multiple content-types.

When any subtype of a given type is acceptable, you'd use something like:

```
Accept: type/*
```

But I need to specify a few particular subtypes, not the entire `type/*` range. It sounds like either of these would work:

```
Accept: type/subtypeA, type/subtypeB
```

or

```
Accept: type/subtypeA,type/subtypeB
```

I'm not clear whether the whitespace following commas matters. I'm also wondering if the request could instead include multple `Accept` headers, like:

```
Accept: type/subtypeA
Accept: type/subtypeB
```

What's the standard way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

According to [MDN Web Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Accept) the syntax should be comma-separated values:

```
Accept: type/subtypeA, type/subtypeB
```

---

Example; I use this when implementing a client in js (using `XMLHttpRequest`):

```js
const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
...

xhr.setRequestHeader('accept', 'application/json, text/plain');

...
```